# How to make M-p and M-n work on rinari-console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, rinari

M-p and M-n do not seem to work in rinari-console, when they should iterate the previously-issued commands list. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some other mode interferes with your keybindings? Try checking with `M-h k` and then entering `M-p` or `M-n`. According to the Rinari docs (`C-h m`) `comint-next-input` and `comint-previous-input` are also bound to `C-down` and `C-up`, maybe those work for you.